# TFS 2012 Build to print a message in the log

Tags: c#, tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-sdk

For TFS 2010 we used:

```cs
context.TrackBuildMessage(message, BuildMessageImportance.High);
context.TrackBuildWarning(message);
context.TrackBuildError(message);
context.TrackBuildWarning(message);
```

For TFS 2012 there appears to only be a Track method on context. However my attempts at testing and tracking an error do not work and show me nothing in the build log.

```cs
context.Track(new CustomTrackingRecord(message, System.Diagnostics.TraceLevel.Error));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In TFS 2012 you need to use the [`TrackingExtensions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/gg433607(v%3Dvs.120)) class.

Just add a using to this namespace to get access to the methods.

```cs
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities;
```